# loading a new page using material button in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I used this code for loading a new page but it does nothing!
Is it related to StatefulWidget? (MaterialButton is under a stful widget)

```
                          MaterialButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              titlenote = titleinput.text;
                              subtitlenote = subtitleinput.text;
                              Navigator.of(context).pop();
                              new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                                return notes();
                              });
                            },
```

---

Here is newpage stless widget:

```
class notes extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: new Column(children: <Widget>[
        new Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 20, 8, 20),
          color: Colors.transparent,
          child: new CheckboxListTile(
            value: true,
            onChanged: (bool a) {},
            title: Text("$titlenote"),
            selected: true,
            checkColor: Colors.green,
            activeColor: Colors.black,
            tristate: true,
            subtitle: Text("$subtitlenote"),
          ),
          alignment: Alignment.center,
        )
      ]),
    );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You creating a `MaterialPageRoute` but you're never pushing it with the navigator. By the way, you can both **pop** and **push** at once by using `pushReplacement` :

```
Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
        return notes();
}));
```

N.B : the keyword `new` is useless since Dart 2, you can remove it every time you see it.